# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure only in server

Tags: java, oracle, ssl, sslhandshakeexception

I am trying to make an HTTP GET petition from Java in Oracle Sql Developer.

In my computer all works fine.

The only thing that doesn't work is when I access https subdomains it gives an `SSLHandshakeException` error (for example if I access https://www.example.com it works, but if I access https://subdomain.example.com it fails)

What I did then was to add the certificate in Java caches and then it worked.

However when I do it on the server, to do it from SQL Developer using PL / SQL calling a Java function, it fails, and I have done the same thing with the certificate.

What I do not know is if you are referencing cacerts in the Java of sql developer, since in my machine if I had to refer to this (-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore = C: \ Oracle \ Middleware \ Oracle_Home \ oracle_common \ jdk \ jre \ lib \ security \ cacerts)

If I do in the Java code this keeps giving error:

```
System.setProperty ("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/path/jdk/jdk6/lib/security/cacerts.jks");
```

How can I know if it is taking the certificates?

My machine: Java 1.7 and 1.8 works
Server: Java 1.6 does not work

Greetings and thanks

Comment: I had a similar problem trying to acces https using jdk1.4. This jdk version does not support https calls so I had to upgrade jdk version. Maybe you had a similiar problem. Take a look on this documentation https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/diagnosing-tls,-ssl,-and-https

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem of Java 6, so in Java 7 and Java 8 works perfectly.